# htaccess rewrite rule fails

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

`.htaccess` is like rocket-science for me (and I guess I am not the only one). I am trying to create some `RewriteRule`s to prettify my URLs.

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /[^?\s]+\.php
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ /$1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule .*[^/]$ $0/ [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^download/(.*)/$ /download.php?fid=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^students/(.*)/ /students.php?show_profile=$1 [L]
```

The PHP redirection works well (I mean, the URLs like `/students.php` become `/students/` automatically). Now, I am particularly intersted in these two lines:

```
RewriteRule ^download/(.*)/$ /download.php?fid=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^students/(.*)/ /students.php?show_profile=$1 [L]
```

So, when I write:

```
http://localhost/students/123
```

it becomes:

```
http://localhost/C:/xampp/htdocs/students/123/
```

and I get a `403` error document.

I dives me crazy, because I would like that this URL: **`http://localhost/students/?show_profile=123#photos`** to be **`http://localhost/students/123/#photos`** (and so on for other URLs)

**My questions**

1. Where am I wrong, and how should my `.htaccess` file look lile?
2. Is there any well-written reference or book that would teach me how to use and write `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rearrange your rules, use option `MultiViews` and fix some regex in URI patterns.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /[^?\s]+\.php
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ /$1/ [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule .*[^/]$ $0/ [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteRule ^download/(.*)/$ download.php?fid=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^students/(.*)/ students.php?show_profile=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

#### [Apache mod_rewrite Technical Details](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/tech.html)

#### [Apache mod_rewrite In-Depth Details](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-deeper-look-at-mod_rewrite-for-apache--net-6708)

Comment: This works perfectly, but you still haven't answered my last question. Could you please provide some sites or books or anything that could help us learn?